# About sonar rule: "Subclasses that add fields should override "equals""

Tags: java, sonarqube

I got a warning from Sonar says the rule `Subclasses that add fields should override "equals"` (`squid:S2160`) get violated.

It was one class A extends another class B with `equals(Object)` method defined. However in the class A, the only new fields is actually a "service" or "dao" type object, and it doesn't make sense to compare it in an `equals` method.

Would like to know is there a graceful way to suppress the warning other than putting in a `@SuppressWarning("squid:S2160")` in the class declaration?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this would make the rule violation disappear, but does it make sense to mark the field as `transient`?

Comment: It will complain if you use `transient` to mark field of class that didn't implement the `Serializable` interface